# React Native Module: Remote pod gets installed but not its dependencies?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have created React Native boilerplate app using:

`npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`

After this I added a podSpec file to the root as shown below:

```
require "json"

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, "package.json")))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = package["title"]
  s.version      = package["version"]
  s.summary      = package["description"]
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                  react-native-test-module
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = package["homepage"]
  # brief license entry:
  # optional - use expanded license entry instead:
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.authors      = { package["authors"] => package["contact"] }
  s.platforms    = { :ios => "9.0" }
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/github_account/react-native-test-module.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

  s.source_files = "ios/**/*.{h,c,cc,cpp,m,mm,swift}"
  s.requires_arc = true
  # ...
  # s.dependency "..."
  s.dependency "React"
end
```

And I am including this pod into another ios App by:

`pod 'MyApp', :git => 'https://github.com/shivam-rallyhealth/rn-content-megazord', :tag => '0.0.19'`

When I do `pod install --repo-update` for some reason, it installs all the files, but not the pod dependencies and so When I do a build, I get this error:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h> 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
```

How do I modify my podSpec such that all the pods also gets installed and not just the module files?

Please note that I am very well able to build the project that lies within `ios` directory of the React Native boilerplate. The problem comes when I try to outsource it to another existing app and then use it there.